# Do I need to define a mime type in this header?

Tags: php, http-headers, jpeg

I am working with scanning images.

Today I made a step forward but I think that I need something more in the header maybe?

Currently a scan request is POSTed to app running on Apache server and PHP 7.0. I receive that post and today I figured out I needed to reply with a custom 201 header.

I have the following custom headers set in PHP

```
header('HTTP/1.1 201', Created);
header('Location: /eSCL/Scans');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
```

After doing I was able to see that a request is now made for an image, from the app to Apache server to /eSCL/Scans/NextDocument. "NextDocument" is actually a softlink to a .jpg, (but may also later be a PDF). The app GETs this file,  I can also see that the server replies with the JPG file . That image should display in the scan app that made the request, but never does.

I think however I need something in the header to tell it it is a JPG , especially given it loads from a softlink with no extension . I tried the following with the same result

```
header('HTTP/1.1 201', Created);
header('Content-type:image/jpeg');
header('Location: /eSCL/Scans');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
```

There must be a magic soup that causes the image to display in the app.I have tried both VueScan and Mopria android app with the same results

Thanks for any ideas in advance

Comment: The response that *redirects* doesn't need the content type header; the response that actually outputs the image body needs it!

Comment: As I already have php files configured to read and execute with no extensions I tried this   


header('Content-type:image/jpeg');
file_get_contents('20190519052127la.jpg');

That did not work.

Comment: Yeah, `file_get_contents` doesn't output the image…